# None of my delays in jQuery works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, title

My script:

```
$(function () {
    $("body").addClass("lost");

    var counter = 0;
    var time = 400;
    var delay = time*5+250;

    if($("body").hasClass("lost")) {
        $("nav").delay(delay).css({'background': 'transparent'});
        $("nav").delay(delay).css({'background-color': '#e30'});
        $(this).find(".slogan").delay(delay).html('USB-stick  is lost');
        var title = "this USB-stick is lost";
    } else {
        var title = "this USB-stick is not lost";
        $(this).find(".slogan").delay(delay).html('USB-stick is not lost');
    }

    var titleTimerId = setInterval(function(){
        document.title = document.title + '.';
        counter++;
        if(counter == 5){
            clearInterval(titleTimerId);
            document.title = title;
        }
    }, time);
});
```

What I want to reach is that all the content change after the var delay time is reached and the title has changed which I have placed in some elements in the script, but this is not working for me

This represents the nav:

```
<nav onclick="window.location=''">
    <img src="//sakesalverda.nl/logo.png" alt="badge html 5" class="logo_nav"/>
    <p>sakesalverda.nl</p>
    <h1 class="slogan">USB-stick</h1>
</nav>
```

Comment: whats nav here ? is it ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/delay/):

> the .delay() method allows us to delay the execution of functions that
>   follow it in the queue. It can be used with the standard effects queue
>   or with a custom queue. Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed;
>   for example this will not delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or
>   .hide() which do not use the effects queue.

`css()` and `html()` methods don't use a queue, you need to wrap them with [`queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.queue/) method, e.g.:

```
$("nav")
    .delay(delay)
    .queue(function (next) {
        $(this).css({'background': 'transparent'});
        next();
    });
```

Comment: One should mention that `delay()` works "automatically" with jQuery animtions (due to the fact that they are in the same animation queue by default).

Comment: @nietonfir true, except this is not a tutorial on `delay()`.

Answer (score -1):

Why not put if else loop in a `setTimeout` function having a timer of `delay` ?

```
setTimeout(function () {
        $("nav").delay(delay).css({
            'background': 'transparent'
        });
        $("nav").delay(delay).css({
            'background-color': '#e30'
        });
        $(this).find(".slogan").delay(delay).html('USB-stick  is lost');
        var title = "this USB-stick is lost";
    }, delay);
```

Similarly for else case

Comment: Everything works except the var title, do you have a solution for that?

Comment: In this case, `delay()` is needless. IMO, the whole point of using `delay()` is to avoid `setTimeout`'s callback hell.